# How was this partial fraction solved with 2 variables?

Tags: partial-fractions, inverse-laplace

How was this partial fraction decomposition done?

[partial fraction image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7lyp.jpg)

Comment: I mean how did the equation above became into that partial fraction

Comment: You seem to be asking why $\frac{1}{s}-\frac{1}{s+\frac1\tau }=\frac{1}{s}-\frac{\tau}{\tau s+1}= \frac1{s(\tau s+1)}$.   You could have an intermediate step of $\frac{(\tau s+1)-\tau s}{s(\tau s+1)}$.

Comment: It was done in the usual way, just viewing $s$ as the variable and $t$ [or $\tau$, hard to tell in image] as a constant.

Comment: @coffeemath oh okay, thank you!